# C++ equivalent for C

Tags: c, arrays

Program for work with arrays in dynamic memory.
Need equivalent for C. Can anybody help?

```
const int n = 6;
char **words = (char**) malloc(n *sizeof(char*));
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    words[i] = (char*)malloc( 50 * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    cin>>words[i];
}

cout<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    if(words[i][0] == 'q')
        cout<<words[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a mixture of C & C++.  Are you wanting to remove the C++ and have it only in C?

Comment: cin & cout are the only bits that would need to change if that's the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only C++ parts there are `cin` and `cout`; you can change them easily:

```
cin>>words[i];
```

becomes

```
scanf("%s", words[i]);
```

or

```
gets(words[i]);
```

while

```
cout<<words[i]<<endl;
```

becomes

```
puts(words[i]);
```

By the way, in the `cin`/`scanf`/`gets` you have a potential buffer overflow, since you are allocating space for 6 characters but you are accepting input of any length. You should do instead:

```
scanf("%6s", words[i]);
```

or (more maintainable, since it uses `n` directly)

```
fgets(words[i], n, stdin);
```

(although this will include the trailing `\n` in the string)

Answer (score 2):

The only C++ features you are using are cin and cout. replace `cin>>words[i]` with `gets(words[i])` and `cout<<words[i]<<endl` with `puts(words[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scanf("%s", &words[i])` to input data from stdin and `printf("%s\n", words[i])` to output to stdout.

Comment: Using the decimal number conversion specification probably wouldn't result in code that he wants.

Comment: Sorry, forgot it was strings :P

Answer (score 0):

As you wish:

```
    const int n = 6;
    char **words = (char**) malloc(n *sizeof(char*));

    int i = 0;

    for( i= 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        words[i] = (char*)malloc( 50 * sizeof(char));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%s", words[i]); 
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if(words[i][0] == 'q')
            printf("%s\n", words[i]);

    }
```